# Not able to get started with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am just starting out with react, while that is going fine, I am not able to start using react-bootstrap here is what my .html file looks like:

```
<html>
<head>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>     
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="react-bootstrap.js"> </script>
<script type="text/jsx">
React.render(
 <p> test </p>
 <Button> test </Button>,
 document.body
);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Does not work.

I get a  Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Question has been solved.

Solution: 
Make it:

```
React.render( <div> <p> test </p> <Button> test </Button> </div>,
    document.body)
```

also add,

```
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
```

Comment: Looks good. Put as an answer and accept it so the question is no longer unanswered.

Comment: Alright, did not know that I can answer my own questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: 
React needs a single root element to render. So, change it to -

```
React.render( <div> <p> test </p> <Button> test </Button> </div>,
    document.body)
```

also add,

```
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
```